# VBA - Hide Excel (Start Pop ups)

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to search a lot to find an answer but all search results just ending up giving a solution to hide the excel interface.

my code is:

```
 ' Start Excel and get Application object. 
        oXL = New Excel.Application

        ' Set some properties 
        oXL.Visible = False
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = False
        oXL.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized

        Dim wkbk As Excel.Workbook = oXL.Workbooks.Add

        'add(worksheet)

        wkbk.Worksheets.Add()

        'open existing work        

        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("...")

        ' Get the active sheet 
        oSheet = DirectCast(oWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
        oSheet.Name = "Sheet1"
```

While it does hide excel ones it is open as a process, it still pops up to open the file and the workbook THEN it goes into hidden.

Is there anyway to prevent the process flashing the excel workbook on the screen for some seconds?

appreciate advises.
Thank you in advance.

mfg Dom

Comment: oXL.Screenupdating = False

Comment: Seems a bit better (faster), but 2 workbooks still pop up for about 1 second

Comment: Try commenting out the WindowState line

Comment: Why are you maximizing Excel if you don't want it visible? That line of code seems likely to be the problem. *Please maximize this window, then don't show it* seems like a logic error to me.

Comment: yea, thanks for pointing it out. I deleted it already when i added your suggestions, so unfortunately it was not the problem